# Как скрыть/отобразить тулбар при нажатии на вьюшку?

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar

Как скрыть/отобразить тулбар при нажатии на вьюшку?

Answer (score 5):

Если тулбар используется самостоятельно, то можно воспользоваться методом setVisibility как для обычной View. В случае использования в качестве ActionBar (выполнено setSupportActionBar(..)) - методами show и hide ActionBar.

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Если кому-то будет нужно - вот решение, которое мне помогло

public void initToolbar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        setTitle(getString(R.string.appName));
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

private void toggleToolbarVisibility() {
        if (isToolbarVisible) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } else {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        isToolbarVisible =! isToolbarVisible;
    }

private class TapGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
            toggleToolbarVisibility();
            return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
        }
    }